How to use library(pdfsearch) when I have a pdf in my working directory
I have downloaded a pdf in my working directory which is the "Document" folder. The name of pdf is kk.pdf
I want to search particular words in this pdf but I have not found a way to do that. I have tried
library(pdfsearch)

directory <- system.file('pdf', "kk.pdf",package = 'pdfsearch')

directory_result <- keyword_directory(directory, 
       keyword = c('new'))

but it does not work.
I suspect that the problem is in how I set up the system.file specification.

Thank you . The library(pdfsearch) works OK. Is this what you are asking?

I see what you mean. No, kk.pdf is the name of the pdf  that has been downloaded to Documents folder. When I type  file, I get
[1] "". It seems that it can not find my pdf.

And when I type result I get
Warning message:
In keyword_search(file, "new", path = FALSE) :
text not recognized in pdf

Yes, I run the code in the vignette and everything is fine. My question is why it does not work when I use my "kk.pdf". Should I specify a different path?  Also what do you mean when you say "you can add your own kk where the sample arxiv.org file is located". Many thanks again. Can you give me a sample code, as an example?

When I type system.file() I get this path
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/library/base"
So I save there my kk.pdf but again the above code that I provided does not work. So, what am I doing wrong?

If your file is in Document you should use keyword_directory("Document",         keyword = c('new')). Not sure why you are using system.file.

Thank yo Axeman, Do you mean the path that leads to Document or just Document?
